# Java moving Main class reference

Tags: java

I was wondering if it was a bad way of programming to move the main reference in the subclass of the software.

It will probably be hard to understand what i really mean so i will do an example.

```
public class Main{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Main app = new Main();
         Toto myToto = new Toto();
         myToto.something(app);
    }
}
public class Toto{ 
    public void something(Main app){

    }
}
```

Comment: Well that code won't compile, as you don't have an instance of `Main` - you can't use `this` in a static method. But there's nothing particularly magical about `main`... you can make it immediately ask something else to do all the real work, sure.

Comment: There is nor real reason for a "Main" class perse. You can define any class as root/main class. Main is just like every other class. But as Jon Skeet already mentiont your code snippet won't compile

Answer (score 1):

"this" is a non-static variable, so it can not be referenced from a static method.
so we can not call something() by using "this" keyword.

Try the below code, it is working correctly

```
class Main{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Toto myToto = new Toto();
     Main m= new Main();
         myToto.something(m);
    }
}
class Toto{ 
    public void something(Main app){

    }
}
```

Comment: My bad I did a mistake in the code, It wasn't the answer to the question. What i mean is to know if it s a bad programming way to reference the Main this way.